# Prevent duplicate datesets with multiple fields in Java

Tags: java, duplicates, dataset

I am currently working with a program that instantiates three number variables each time you run the program.  For example:

```
(companyID, groupID, hostID)

The 1st time when I run it
(int companyID = 1; int groupID = 1, int hostID = 1)

2nd time
(1, 1, 1)

3rd time
(1, 1, 1)

4th
(1, 2, 1)

5th
(6, 4, 3)

...
```

Is there a way that I can save the three numbers in a dataset everytime when I run the program, and at the same time prevent duplicate numbers in the same order from being stored in the dataset?  In the example above, only one instance of 1, 1, 1 would be stored.

So the end results stored in the dataset are only (1,1,1),(1,2,1),(6,4,3).

Thanks.

Comment: the simplest way would be to write those IDs to a file that your program will read at its start. When the program is about to end it just writes to that file all the contents of the data set. This way you have a really basic database that's just stored on a file.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Thanks.  But even in this case, how do I make sure no duplicate gets written.  Is there a way I can easily track the combination of three numbers?

Comment: You can store your tuples in a class (that will just contain 3 elements). Override #compare, or use your own method to compare two of your classes. Then just store them in file between stars as suggested by  @RAZ_Muh_Taz. In program you can store them in any structure, such as List. Also, you can implement [comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and use any Set (like LinkedHashSet). This way you can easily see if that element is already in set using Set#contains method

Comment: @mr.Tropez Thanks for the clarification.  So based the second way, do I just store them in a int array int[1,1,1] and then add that array to Set<int[]>  ?

Comment: @000000000000000000000, no, you will still need to use some wrapper class for that. I posted a code example of set usage in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**CODE**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatasetUnique {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //  Data to insert
        int[] one =     {1,2,3};
        int[] two =     {2,3,4};
        int[] three =   {1,2,3};
        int[] four =    {7,8,9};
        int[] five =    {2,3,4};

        //  Data inserted
        List<dataSet> allContent = new ArrayList<>();

        //  1 - Insert data
        insert(new dataSet(one), allContent);
        insert(new dataSet(two), allContent);
        insert(new dataSet(three), allContent);
        insert(new dataSet(four), allContent);
        insert(new dataSet(five), allContent);

        //  2 - Print data
        System.out.println(allContent.toString());

    }

    //  Insert a dataset inside list if doesnt exists
    private static void insert(dataSet dataSetToInsert, List<dataSet> allContent){
        if(allContent.size() == 0){
            allContent.add(dataSetToInsert);
        }else{
            for(dataSet ds: allContent){
                if(dataSetToInsert.equals(ds)){
                    return;
                }               
            }
            allContent.add(dataSetToInsert);
        }
    }

    //  Class for each dataSet
    private static class dataSet{

        int firstNumber;
        int secondNumber;
        int thirdNumber;

        public dataSet(int[] dataSet) {
            super();
            this.firstNumber = dataSet[0];
            this.secondNumber = dataSet[1];
            this.thirdNumber = dataSet[2];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            dataSet other = (dataSet) obj;          
            if (firstNumber != other.firstNumber)
                return false;
            if (secondNumber != other.secondNumber)
                return false;
            if (thirdNumber != other.thirdNumber)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "\n" + firstNumber + " " + secondNumber + " "+ thirdNumber + "\n";
        }       
    }


}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
1 2 3
, 
2 3 4
, 
7 8 9
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need some wrapper class. You can store 3 ints, or an array of ints, it's up to you. 
You need to implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.
And if you will use Set class for this task, note that [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) won't work, cause it's not based on natural ordering. [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) will.
Here is the simple code example of your class.

Of course, this doesn't include the part where you store your class in a file, but allows you to manage duplicates while you work. Then you can just write all elements from set to file, and they will be unique. And load elements from file to set on start.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Test {
    public static final class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple> {
        public int x1;
        public int x2;
        public int x3;

        public Tuple(int x1, int x2, int x3) {
            this.x1 = x1;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.x3 = x3;
        }

        /**
         * You don't need equal method to work with sets (and this is not even overriding basic equals method,
         * but it's just an example of how you can easily compare your tuples
         */
        public boolean equals(Tuple obj) {
            return this.x1 == obj.x1 && this.x2 == obj.x2 && this.x3 == obj.x3;
        }

        /**
         * Check javadoc for this, but it's just a way to tell if one tuple is more, equal or less then another
         */
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Tuple o) {
            if (o.x1 != this.x1) {
                return new Integer(o.x1).compareTo(this.x1);
            }
            if (o.x2 != this.x2) {
                return new Integer(o.x2).compareTo(this.x2);
            }
            return new Integer(o.x3).compareTo(this.x3);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + x1 + " " + x2 + " " + x3 + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
         * Note, that HashSet won't work because it doesn't depend on natural ordering of elements.
         * TreeSet does, and it will work fine for your purpose.
         */
        Set<Tuple> tuples = new TreeSet<>();
        tuples.add(new Tuple(1, 1, 1));
        tuples.add(new Tuple(1, 2, 3));
        tuples.add(new Tuple(1, 1, 1));
        tuples.add(new Tuple(2, 3, 4));
        tuples.add(new Tuple(2, 3, 4));
        tuples.add(new Tuple(1, 2, 3));

        for (Tuple tuple: tuples) {
            System.out.println(tuple);
        }
    }
}`
```

Output of this will be

```
[2 3 4]
[1 2 3]
[1 1 1]
```

No duplicates were put in Set.